# How to use filter and search bar on the same form in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="job-filter">
  <h3>Filter <img id="icon-filter" @click="showfilter" :style="{ 'display': display.btn_show_filter }" src="../assets/recruit/angle-down-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""> <img id="icon-close-filter" :style="{ 'display': display.btn_close_filter }" @click="closefilter" src="../assets/recruit/close-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></h3>
  <div  class="radio-group" id="group-filter" :style="{ 'display': display.group_filter }" >
    <div class="radio-check" v-for="(check, index) in checks" :key="index">
      <input type="radio" :id="index"  name="fav_language" :value="check" v-model="selected" >
      <label  :for="index">{{check}}</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <div class="search-top flex-wrap">
      <div class="search-input">
        <input type="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Nhập từ khóa để tìm kiếm">
        <button @click="search"><img src="../assets/recruit/search.svg" alt=""></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-item"  v-for="(item, index) in filtered" :key="index">
   <a href=""><h3 class="mleft-27">{{item.position}}</h3></a>     
    <div>
      <img src="../assets/recruit/years.svg" alt="">
      <b>{{item.exprerience}}</b>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="../assets/recruit/luong.svg" alt="">
      <b>{{item.salary}}</b>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="../assets/recruit/diadiem.svg" alt="">
      <b>{{item.headequarters}}</b>
    </div>
    <h6>{{item.createdAt}}</h6>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>{{item.content1}}</li>
  <li>{{item.content2}}</li>
  <li>{{item.content3}}</li>
</ul>
```

I've done with the filter, but I'm having trouble building the search bar....... i'm  using the filtered checkbox to handle the filter but i still haven't figured out how to make both work and show the same place.

**My logic code:**

```
export default {
  data(){
     return{     
       checks:['All','Developer','Tester', 'Designer', 'Support',],
       infojobs:[{
                  genres: 'Developer',
                  position:'Senior Java Engineer, Big Data',
                  exprerience:'3-5 Years',
                  salary:'',
                  headequarters:'',
                  content1:'1',
                  content2:'2
                  createdAt: "3"
                 },
                 {
                  genres: 'Designer',
                  position:'Creative professional designer ',
                  exprerience:'1-3 Years',
                  salary:'',
                  headequarters:'',
                  content1:'',
                  content2:'1',
                  content3:'2',
                  createdAt: "3"
                  }
        ],
        selected: 'All',
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filtered() {
        console.log(this.selected)
        if(this.selected=='All'){
            return this.infojobs
        }
        else{ 
          return this.infojobs.filter(i => i.genres === this.selected)
        }
    },                
  },
```

I hope to handle the search bar and filter without conflict, hope to get some help, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `watchers`.

Code explanation:

- Define an extra variable `showJobs` in `data()`
- Place a `watcher` on `selected` variable which will show the jobs on basis of filter selection
- Place a `watcher` on `search` variable which triggers the search functionality only if user inputs more than 2 characters, if not, we will be showing default filtered jobs. In addition, we can use `debounce` to add a delay of `500ms` while searching the jobs.

---

```
watch: {
 selected(newVal) {
   if (newVal === "All") {
     this.showJobs = this.infojobs;
   } else {
     this.showJobs = this.infojobs.filter((i) => i.genres === newVal);
   }
 },

 search: _.debounce(function (newVal) {
   if (newVal.length > 2) {
     let searchedJobs = this.showJobs.filter((job) =>
       job.position.toLowerCase().includes(newVal.toLowerCase())
     );

     this.showJobs = searchedJobs;
   } else {
     if (this.selected === "All") {
      this.showJobs = this.infojobs;
     } else {
      this.showJobs = this.infojobs.filter((i) => i.genres === this.selected);
    }
   }
 }, 500)
}
```

Note: You need import `debounce` from lodash library in the component.

---

**EDIT**: Here as you mentioned your requirement in the comment, you can use the same logic in the `searchJob` function under `methods`, so it triggers the 'search' functionality on button click and yea, don't forget to remove the `watcher` for `search` variable.

```
searchJob() {
   if (this.search.length > 2) {
     let searchedJobs = this.showJobs.filter((job) =>
       job.position.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
     );

     this.showJobs = searchedJobs;
   } else {
     if (this.selected === "All") {
      this.showJobs = this.infojobs;
     } else {
      this.showJobs = this.infojobs.filter((i) => i.genres === this.selected);
    }
   }
 },
```

Comment: It looks very professional but it's a bit confusing for me, can you give me a more explicit demo? Thanks u <3

Comment: What part is confusing for you here in this code? Tell me, I will explain you.

Comment: If you are not aware about watchers in VueJs then you can refer the doc: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html

Comment: So how should I put the v-model in the checkbox and the search bar so that they work together?

Comment: For the filter, you have a radio input with v-model="selected", keep it as it is. Whenever you select a filter, the watcher on the variable will trigger and update "this.showJobs" variable with filtered jobs. For the search functionality, you won't need 'search' button. The watcher on 'search' variable will trigger as soon as you have more than 2 characters in the input field and it would find the related jobs as per your 'search' input from the 'this.showJobs' array and will return only the 'searchedJobs'. This way you could have both 'filter' and 'search' functionality working together.

Comment: Basically 'watchers' keep an eye on your variable and they trigger as soon as the variable's value changes or gets updated. On that trigger, you can do some logic as per your requirement. Here, in your case we have placed 'watcher' on your 'selected' and 'search' variables defined in the 'data()'. That's why we don't need to click the 'Search' button. As soon as you type something to search it will trigger the logic to search the data from your 'this.showJobs' array giving you real time experience.

Comment: I understood that, but the problem required by my superiors is to enter the search button :(

Comment: I've edited my answer as per your requirement. Check it. Note: You can either use methods if you require search feature on button click or watcher if no button is needed. Don't use both.

Comment: Let me ask one more question is in the checkbox I give v-model='selected' so how do I put v-model in the search bar? thank you

Comment: I tried your way and it gives error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Comment: Please add your code snippet and let me see it

Comment: For search input => <input type="search" v-model="search" />
For filter radio button => <input type="radio" :id="index"  name="fav_language" :value="check" v-model="selected" />

You have used correctly as given in the question. Just make sure you have defined 'selected' and 'search' variables in 'data()' property.

Comment: I followed the instructions, in data() i have search: "",
and showJobs: [], I use v-for="(item, index) in showJobs" :key="index" but it gives an error when clicking the search button like this: TypeError: handler.apply is not a functions", Looking forward to your help, many thanks

Comment: My bad. There was a typo in the 'search' function. I used 'newVal' instead of 'this.search' while searching the jobs. Please check the updated answer of Edit section. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yes the search button is working but when I start to visit the site it has no data and the radio checkbox is not working, can you please check it again, thanks.

Comment: If you have free time, can you help me? Thanks u <3

Comment: I need to see your whole file's code. I don't think adding this function and watcher have affected to any of your other code.

Comment: I can push the text file for you to see, can I use teamview or can you give me a link to FB, tele... is it possible? thank you

Comment: here is my full code snippet notepad link: [https://anotepad.com/notes/ci2tbs3g]

Comment: Please make the notepad snippet publicly accessible.

Comment: Yes this is the standard link, please check it out, thank you very much [ https://anotepad.com/notes/ci2tbs3g ]

Comment: 1. Just use empty array for showJobs in data() => showJobs: []
2. You haven't added watcher for 'selected' variable in your code. That is required
3. Your 'search' is only working when clicking on button, as per the requirement. 

With the above said changes, it seems to be working fine for me!

Comment: What should I put in watch to default to the site showing all? i gave watch:{
 selected(selected) {
   if (selected === "All") {
     this.showJobs = this.infojobs;
   } else {
     this.showJobs = this.infojobs.filter((i) => i.genres === this.selected);
   }
 },

Comment: And one more thing is when the checkbox in each category will display the search results by that category, it's the backlog, hope you can give me some ideas, thank you

Comment: This will be the code that needs to be added inside the watcher.

selected(newVal) {
   if (newVal === "All") {
     this.showJobs = this.infojobs;
   } else {
     this.showJobs = this.infojobs.filter((i) => i.genres === newVal);
   }
 },

I'm not getting your last comment.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that by default when I first enter the page no data is displayed and the search button when the check box is in the "developer" position it can still search for the "designer" position. :((

Answer (score 0):

```
computed: {
  filtered() {
    let finalFilter = [...this.infojobs];
    console.log(this.selected)
    if (this.selected !== 'All') {
      finalFilter =this.infojobs.filter(i => i.genres === 
    }
    if (this.search.trim()) {
      finalFilter  = finalFilter.filter((i) => Object.values(i).some(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
    }
    return finalFiter
  },                
},
```

You don't need if-else both. just use if condition.

Comment: Can you review your code? it is missing, the following example ===. thanks u

Comment: I corrected the code: filtered() {
    let finalFilter = [...this.infojobs];
    console.log(this.selected)
    if (this.selected !== 'All') {
      finalFilter =this.infojobs.filter(i => i.genres === this.selected)
    }
    if (this.search.trim()) {
      finalFilter = finalFilter.filter((i) => Object.values(i).some(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))))
    }
    return finalFiter
  }, but it gives an error.

Comment: It gives an error that: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')"

Comment: add <search:""> in your data() function.

Comment: I understood your way of doing it but can you tell me how instead of listening for the change in the search bar it needs to click the button to work?